# Difference between return 0 and -1

Tags: c++

Can anyone please explain the difference between return 0 and -1 used in c++? I have read many articles and posts from other programmers saying that return 0 means the program is successful and -1 means the program has an error. But what I don't get is why use these statements when the compiler will generate an error if there is one in the program anyway? Please explain in detail what these statements really mean.

Comment: Please provide [mre] that illustrates what you are asking about. As-is your question is hard to understand. Are you asking about values returned by `main`? If so, "_But what I don't get is why use these statements when the compiler will generate an error if there is one in the program anyway?_" doesn't make much sense. What error would be generated by `return 0;` statement in `main`?

Comment: *" But what I don't get is why use these statements when the compiler will generate an error if there is one in the program anyway?"* Its not because your code compiled that it is correct. The compiler can't check everything, it's mathematically impossible. Much less verify that it will run as you expect. You are confusing compilation error with run-time error. For example, what happens if, when run, your program needs to read a file that doesn't exist? The compiler couldn't possible check that for you.

Comment: ***when the compiler will generate an error if there is one in the program anyway?*** This is a wrong assumption. A program can return a failure that is not related to a bug in the software, crash... Maybe the user entered bad data. Maybe a file to read is corrupt so the program exited gracefully telling the OS that there was a failure. So that a script that launched your program knows not to continue.

Comment: @alteredinstance I'm curious what part of my comment you consider uses jargon?

Comment: Common convention is for programs to return 0 when successful, other values may indicate errors.  A compiler should return 0 for successful compilation and may return a -1 for an error found during compilation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Talking about compilers and run-time errors are basic, sure, but I'm assuming OP doesn't really understand those concepts if they don't even know what `return 0;` does. I'm just trying to ensure OP can understand their issue, instead of telling OP they are wrong

Comment: @alteredinstance *"compiler will generate an error"* leads me to believe that they do understand what a compiler and compilation means. It's not a stretch to assume that if they understand what compilation means they know what run-time means. Or at least that they can guess when it's presented as distinct from compile time.

Comment: Just trying to be newbie-friendly.

Answer (score 5):

This has absolutely nothing to do with the compiler.

The compiler will report syntax errors.

The return codes are used to report if the program completed successfully.
("Success" depends on what the program was intended to do).

For example:

```
// Program SearchTerm "term to find"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   bool search_successful = false;

   [ ... do work ... ]

    if (search_successful)
    {
        return 0;  // The search worked.
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;  // The search failed
    }
}
```

### Example usage:

```
SearchTerm "Microsoft"
More than 1 million results found... returned Success

SearchTerm "asldfjpu"
No results found... returned Failure
```

---

When a program reports success or failure, it can be integrated in the Scripts such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
if `SearchTerm "Microsoft"`; then
    GetTopResults "Microsoft"
else
    echo "No results found, no Top Results to retrieve"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `int main()` is the so called exit code of the program. This is already so in C (which has no exceptions) and is there to basically tell to caller how it went. A exit code of zero means success and every other exit code (but normally one uses only positive ones) means that something went wrong. Sometimes programms will document what a certain exit code means i.e. if a file was not found or an allocation failed etc.

This is a very important part of scripting for example bash scripts, which know in this way if a called command went right or wrong. Even if your program crashes with an exception, the programm will generate an exit code (which will be non-zero). In bash you can see the exit code of the last run program with `echo $?`, so you can check that out for yourself.

Comment: The only portable exit codes are 0, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means that anything other then `0` means something bad happened during execution of your program. The program could not deal with it so it exited with the status code.

Often when working with shell you will notice that some of commands exit with non 0 status code. You can check that value by running `echo $?` command.

And finally you can use return codes to communicate to the client what happend. That is if you describe what return codes can your program return.

Answer (score 0):

A `return` is simply the value returned by any function. At the end of a function, the computer is able to accept a single value to take back with it when it returns to the rest of the program. In the case of the function `int main()`, with which you are probably familiar, the return value is used as an indication of the success of the program.

`main()` is simply the entry point of the program you are running. It's the first function called by your computer when the program starts (with some exceptions)
Theoretically, you could return any integer from `main()`.

The only "accepted" thing is that anything that is non-zero is generally some error or fault. So a `return 0;` indicates success, while `return -1;` might indicate some kind of error. The truth is, the value returned from `main()` doesn't really matter, and won't affect how your program runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about the value returned by `main`, there are two defined values that you can return: `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`. Those values are defined in the header `<stdlib.h>` and in the header `<cstdlib>`. You can also return the value 0, which is equivalent to returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`. There are no other meaningful values in C or C++, although your implementation can provide meanings for other values.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are returning 0 or -1 from the main program as your program exits. What this does is inform the calling program the success or failure of the program. This is not very handy if you just run the program at a command prompt but if your program is called within a script (Perl,PHP, python, PowerShell, etc) you can test to see if the program was successful.

In a nutshell, if your program is called by another program, the calling program can test for success or failure and respond appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

> the program is successful and -1 means the program has an error.
>
> Please explain in detail what these statements really mean.

There are situations where a function cannot proceed further, and cannot complete the task that it is specified for it. Such situation is typically called an error. There are many possible sources of errors. One example of that is a function that has pre-conditions for the inputs that were not satisfied by the caller of the function. An example of such pre-condition is square root function that calculates rational numbers (i.e. not complex): There is no result for negative input.

When an error is encountered, it must somehow be communicated to the caller. There are many techniques, but we shall not cover all of them in detail here. I'll mention that one option in C++ is exceptions. Exceptions technique has some useful properties, but it is not universally applicable to all situations.

Another, very simple technique is to return an error code which is an integer value. If we choose 0 to signify no error, the caller of the function can check for error with following pattern:

```
int error = function(arguments)
if (error) {
    // handle error here
}
```

This pattern is very common in C APIs. C++ inherits C standard library, and it is common to take advantage of C libraries so it is common to encounter this in C++ as well.

Sometimes, a function needs to use the return value for some other purpose. For example, the `open` call from POSIX standard returns an integer called "file descriptor", which is a positive integer. Since some of the values in the domain of the return type are not used (negative numbers), it can be used to represent error condition as well. Although any negative number is available, -1 was chosen, and this is also quite conventional. In some other APIs different negative numbers represent different errors. Another approach is to store error information elsewhere. The chosen approach in POSIX is to store the error code in a separate variable.

---

In conclusion: Integer return values are a technique of communicating errors, and 0 is conventionally used to represent success and -1 is often used to represent erroneous execution. The meaning of the return value of a function should be documented by the implementer, and the documentation should be studied carefully by the user of the function.

---

> But what I don't get is why use these statements when the compiler will generate an error if there is one in the program anyway?

It's unclear what you expect here. The compiler cannot read the programmer's mind and know all cases where the program should have an error. It can only tell whether the program is well-formed or not (and maybe give some helpful warnings about obvious mistakes if you're lucky).

It is the programmer's responsibility to consider the error conditions of the program.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between 0 and -1, as far as the compiler is concerned, is that they are two different numbers. Nothing is assumed whatsoever about their "success" or "failure" status (except in main in which the return value is ignored anyway).

The rest are (mostly bad) conventions used by developers. Usually < 0 for failure and 0 for success and you have created a nice bug when you test against `bool` (in which -1 is `true` and 0 is `false`).

One should use enums or, at least, something more recognizable as in windows HRESULT.